# Creating a non-directed self referential association in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I am creating a rails3 app that will include the ability for users to add other users as friends.  This relationship should behave like facebook friendships, wherein friendships must be mutual, versus twitter friendships, wherein users can friend another user without reciprocation.  I don't know how to do this without creating two separate relationships between the two users.  Here's what I have so far:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
end
```

To create a friendship, I call:

```
@user1.friends << @user2
```

This only creates the relationship in one direction, however.   @user2.friends is still empty.  The only way I know how to make it work right now is to just call:

```
@user1.friends << @user2
@user2.friends << @user1
```

Comment: No, that still won't work.  The only way to see the other side of this relationship with the current configuration is if I add a "has_many :users, :through => :friendships" line to User.

Comment: But if I do that, it requires me to separate users and friends into two different groups, which I do not want to do.

Comment: There used to be an acts_as_network plugin for 2.x that did the two relationships behind the scenes and gave you an interface to the union of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this tutorial helps:

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Specifically the "Inverse Relationships" section:

"When creating self-referential relationships it’s important to remember that we’re only creating one side of the relationship. . . . We need two Friendship records to create a mutual friendship."

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base   

  has_many :friendships   
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships   

  has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"   
  has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user   

  #rest of class omitted. 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use [`before_save_collection_association`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html#method-i-before_save_collection_association) callback? It will give you some additional abilities.